# Hash only LETTERS using Horner's method in java

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I understand how Horner's method in hashing works but I am having issues hashing a string that may contain non-alphabetical characters and I want to hash just the alphabetical characters. I want to ignore non-alphabetical characters and hash just alphabetic characters
Here's is the code I have done for this but doesn't work entirely

```
private int hash(String key){
int constant = 27;

int lastHashValue = key.charAt(0); //convert the first char to ascii first 
                                   //because for each character we multiply the constant by the
                                   // hash code by the constant. 

 for(int i = 1; i < key.length(); i++){

   if( Character.isLetter(key.charAt(i)) ){ //checks if it is a letter 
      lastHashValue  = (key.charAt(i) + (constant * lastHashValue) ) % array.length;
    }
 }

 return lastHashValue;
}
```

Here is the issue I have: What if the first character is a non-alphabetic character. How do I ignore it? (knowing that we need to get the first character hash code to move to the next).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize `lastHashValue` to `0` and start looping at index `0`.

```
 int lastHashValue = 0; 

 for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++){

   if( Character.isLetter(key.charAt(i)) ){ //checks if it is a letter 
      lastHashValue  = (key.charAt(i) + (constant * lastHashValue) ) % array.length;
    }
 }
```